# L_ERRORCODE0 : 10401 returned by DoReferenceTransaction

Tags: php, paypal, express-checkout

I have done payment of $990, it gets success. After that I am trying to do payment of $2490 it giving **error : 10401.**

For both payments I am using **DoReferenceTransaction** API call (same billing agreement ID).

Why its happening?

Here is my **NVP:**

```
    $nvpstr = '&REFERENCEID=' . $billing_agreement_id;
    $nvpstr.='&PAYMENTACTION=' . $paymentType;
    $nvpstr.= '&AMT=' . $FinalPaymentAmt;
    $nvpstr.= '&CURRENCYCODE=' . $currencyCodeType;
    $nvpstr.='&L_ITEMCATEGORY0=Digital';
    $nvpstr.='&DESC=' . urlencode("LMS Recurring Payment( $" . $_SESSION["Payment_Amount"] . " )");
    $nvpstr.="&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMCATEGORY0=Digital";
    $nvpstr.="&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0=1";
    $nvpstr.="&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0=LMS Billing";
    $nvpstr.="&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0=" . $_SESSION["Payment_Amount"];
    $nvpstr.="&L_NAME0=Test Name";
    $nvpstr.="&L_DESC0=" . urlencode("LMS Recurring Payment( $" . $_SESSION["Payment_Amount"] . " )");
    $nvpstr.="&L_AMT0=" . $_SESSION["Payment_Amount"];
    $nvpstr.="&ITEMAMT=" . $_SESSION["Payment_Amount"];
    $nvpstr.="&L_QTY0=1";
    $nvpstr.="&RECURRING=Y";
```

Please guide me, so that I can overcome this error.

**Note:** Error not comes when transaction payments are done in sequence like:

$99

$249

$3990

Answer (score 1):

[Paypal documentation says](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/errorcodes/):

> Code 10401 
> Transaction refused because of an invalid argument.
> Order total is invalid. TotalOrder amount is invalid.

**In my experience error 10004 has appear when has incompatibility between methods SetExpressCheckout and ( in your case ) DoReferenceTransaction**

**So please check TotalOrder amount!**

Comment: Hi, Pavel...
Thank You for your kind response, my problem has been solved. It was due to more than two decimal points in AMT. **solved**.